# error: cannot access DrawerLayout when using AppCompatActivity

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat, android-design-library

Using appcompat `"com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"`

I am not using `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` in my activity. Even though i am getting the following error when run application on to test device,

```
error: cannot access DrawerLayout
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   ^
  class file for android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout not found
```

app.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xx.xx"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility 1.8
    targetCompatibility 1.8
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.7'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Activity

```
package com.xx.xx;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private LinearLayout stateContainer;
private ToggleButton toggleNw;
private ToggleButton toggleLocation;
private AppCompatEditText etLanguageCode;
private AppCompatEditText etCountryCode;
private AppCompatTextView txSplittedText;
private ToggleButton toggleState;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    stateContainer = findViewById(R.id.stateContainer);
    toggleNw = findViewById(R.id.toggleNw);
    toggleLocation = findViewById(R.id.toggleLocation);
    etLanguageCode = findViewById(R.id.etLanguageCode);
    etCountryCode = findViewById(R.id.etCountryCode);
    txSplittedText = findViewById(R.id.txSplittedText);
    toggleState = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleState);
}
}
```

Comment: is there 'com.android.support:design:x.x.x' dependency in your build.gradle file

Comment: Please post the code of your entire of MainActivity. or atleast the starting part.

Comment: @Sree Yes, com.android.support:design:28.0.0

Comment: @Sujith please share your `build.gradle` file with question

Comment: @Nilesh Rathod let me know why do you feel this is marked as duplicate.

Comment: Just curious, but why are you targeting version `21` of the Android SDK? Note that the Play Console does not allow apps that are not targeting the latest version of Android to be uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

> class file for android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout not found

The `DrawerLayout` is not included in the support design library. It is inside the `android.support.v4` libraries.

You can add the dependency `com.android.support:drawerlayout:28.0.0`.

Answer (score 0):

The DrawerLayout class file not found,
You can add the dependency `com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0`.